# IF condition along with WHERE NOT EXISTS mysql

Tags: mysql

Below is my query :

```
SELECT *
FROM  A WHERE  NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT *
   FROM   B
   WHERE A.ItemCode = B.ItemCode AND A.Store = B.StoreName GROUP BY B.ItemCode,B.StoreName) AND A.Store='Food Store'
```

I wish to add a condition if B.Date <= '2014-05-10' then only the above query should work.
Suppose:-
A Table: 10 records, B Table: 5 records of today and 3 records of yesterday are present. if yesterday's date is selected, the output should be 7 records from Table A and if today's date is selected then 2 records from Table A should be found(5+3) and if day-before yesterday is selected then all records from Table A should be found.

Kindly help me.

Comment: i want the sub-query to run only if B.Date <= '2014-5-10'

Comment: You mean `SELECT * FROM A WHERE B.Date > '2014-5-10' OR NOT EXISTS()...` ?

Comment: Suppose:- A Table: 10 records, B Table: 5 records of today and 3 records of yesterday are present. if yesterday's date is selected, the output should be 7 records from Table A and if today's date is selected then 2 records from Table A should be found(5+3) and if day-before yesterday is selected then all records from Table A should be found.

Answer (score 0):

U can simply add it at the end if i'm not mistaken

```
 SELECT * FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE A.ItemCode = B.ItemCode AND A.Store = B.StoreName GROUP BY B.ItemCode,B.StoreName) AND A.Store='Food Store' AND B.Date < '2014-05-10'
```

Comment: No, you can't do that. You can add that condition in the subquery `WHERE` though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the condition in the part of the query where `B` is known.  That is in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM  A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM B
                  WHERE A.ItemCode = B.ItemCode AND
                        A.Store = B.StoreName AND
                        B.Date <= '2014-05-10'
                 ) AND
      A.Store = 'Food Store';
```

Note that you do not need the `group by` in the subquery.  You don't care *how many* or *which* rows exist, just whether any meet those conditions.  I also replaced the `*` by `1`.  With the `group by`, the `*` is misleading because it has no aggregation functions.  I usually use `1` for `exists` clauses.

Comment: Above query gives same records whether B.Date <= '2014-05-10' is added or not.

Comment: @user3631928 . . . You have provided no data, so that might be totally appropriate.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle with some sample data?